# One Hot Encoding of complex variables

Tags: r, strsplit, dummy-variable, splitstackshape, one-hot-encoding

I have a dataset where all my data is categorical and I would like to use one hot encoding for further analysis.

Main issues I would like to resolve:

- Some cells contain many text in one cell (an example will follow).
- Some numerical values need to be changed to factor for further process.

Data with 3 headings Age, info & Target

```
mydf <- structure(list(Age = c(99L, 10L, 40L, 15L), Info =         c("c(\"good\", \"bad\", \"sad\"", 
"c(\"nice\", \"happy\", \"joy\"", "NULL", "c(\"okay\", \"nice\", \"fun\", \"wild\", \"go\""
), Target = c("Boy", "Girl", "Boy", "Boy")), .Names = c("Age", 
"Info", "Target"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to create one hot encoding of all these variables shown above so it will look like the following:

```
       Age_99 Age_10 Age_40 Age_15 good bad sad nice happy joy null okay nice fun wild go Boy Girl 
         1      0       0     0      1   1    1   0     0    0   0   0    0   0   0    0   0   0
         0      1       0     0      0   0    0   1     1    1   0   0    0   0   0    0   0   1
```

Some of the questions on SO I have checked are [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24142576/one-hot-encoding-in-r-categorical-to-dummy-variables) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384506/create-new-dummy-variable-columns-from-categorical-variable).

Comment: How did you get this data in this form to begin with? Can you `dput` these few lines for us?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R DataFrame - One Hot Encoding of column containing multiple terms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39778387/r-dataframe-one-hot-encoding-of-column-containing-multiple-terms)

Answer (score 2):

I would suppose that the following should work:

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(magrittr)

suppressWarnings({                               ## Just to silence melt
  mydf %>%                                       ## The dataset
    as.data.table(keep.rownames = TRUE) %>%      ## Convert to data.table
    .[, Info := gsub("c\\(|\"", "", Info)] %>%   ## Strip out c( and quotes
    cSplit("Info", ",") %>%                      ## Split the "Info" column
    melt(id.vars = "rn") %>%                     ## Melt everyting except rn
    dcast(rn ~ value, fun.aggregate = length)    ## Go wide
})
#    rn 10 15 40 99 Boy Girl NULL bad fun go good happy joy nice okay sad wild NA
# 1:  1  0  0  0  1   1    0    0   1   0  0    1     0   0    0    0   1    0  2
# 2:  2  1  0  0  0   0    1    0   0   0  0    0     1   1    1    0   0    0  2
# 3:  3  0  0  1  0   1    0    1   0   0  0    0     0   0    0    0   0    0  4
# 4:  4  0  1  0  0   1    0    0   0   1  1    0     0   0    1    1   0    1  0
```

Here's the sample data I used:

```
mydf <- structure(list(Age = c(99L, 10L, 40L, 15L), Info = c("c(\"good\", \"bad\", \"sad\"", 
    "c(\"nice\", \"happy\", \"joy\"", "NULL", "c(\"okay\", \"nice\", \"fun\", \"wild\", \"go\""
    ), Target = c("Boy", "Girl", "Boy", "Boy")), .Names = c("Age", 
    "Info", "Target"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @A Handcart And Mohair for your answer, but I have a few questions.. where do you get the variable "rn" from. Furthermore, you only split the variable "Info", but "Age" &Target gets also split. is this a norm for cSplit library or can you select which varaibles to split which not to split. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `grepl` function to scan each string for whatever you are looking for, and use `ifelse` to fill the column appropriately.
Something like:

```
 # This will create a new column labeled 'good' with 1 if the string contains and 0 if not 
 data$good =  ifelse(grepl("good",data$info),1, 0)
 # and do this for each variable of interest
```

And at the end you can remove the `info` column if you'd like. This way you don't have to make any new data tables.

```
 data$info <- NULL
```

Note that you should change 'data' to whatever the actual name of your data set is. 
As for the problem with age, no need to change it into factors, just use:

`data$age99 = ifelse(data$Age == 99, 1,0) # and so forth for the other ages`

Comment: thanks, but the main issue for me is the one hot encoding right now.