# R "explode" columns of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a quite interesting problem that I am looking a smart and possible efficient solution for.

I have a data frame that looks like this.

```
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  track_id   tag1   tag2  tag3   tag4   tag5
     <int>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1  1550729  54087 109806 46869 183258  54337
2  1184201 201327   3668 46208 205245 189631
3  3763749 194264 194413  3424  91383 205245
4  2674608 198998 107401  2327   4425 107398
5  1999180  54087   4425 75574 239459   2397
6  3048820  11242 205245  2474  11056  72354
```

What I would like is to keep the track_id in the first row but to explode the tags, and where one track has the particular ID I would like to put a true value, namely one.

To be clearer, let's suppose I start from a smaller one:

```
  track_id   tag1   tag2 
1  1550729  54087 109806 
2  1184201 201327   3668
```

After the transformation I would like to get at something like

```
  track_id   54087   109806  201327   3668   
1  1550729       1        1       0      0
2  1184201       0        0       1      1
```

Is this something possible quickly or I should roll out a solution by hand?

Comment: Search for "dummy variable" and/or "one-hot encoding"

Comment: First convert the `tag` variables to factors and then `model.matrix(~ . + 0, data = your_data_frame)`. Suggested dupes: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11952706/903061, https://stackoverflow.com/q/24142576/903061

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A solution from `dplyr` and `tidyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dt2 <- dt %>%
  gather(tag, value, -track_id) %>%
  select(-tag) %>%
  mutate(Occurrence = 1) %>%
  spread(value, Occurrence, fill = 0)
```

**DATA**

```
dt <- read.table(text = "  track_id   tag1   tag2  tag3   tag4   tag5
1  1550729  54087 109806 46869 183258  54337
2  1184201 201327   3668 46208 205245 189631
3  3763749 194264 194413  3424  91383 205245
4  2674608 198998 107401  2327   4425 107398
5  1999180  54087   4425 75574 239459   2397
6  3048820  11242 205245  2474  11056  72354",
                 header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `melt()` and `dcast()` from the `data.table` package, this becomes a "one-liner":

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df), id.vars = "track_id")[, dcast(.SD, track_id ~ value, length)]
```

> ```
>    track_id 2327 2397 2474 3424 3668 4425 11056 11242 46208 46869 54087 54337 72354 75574
> 1:  1184201    0    0    0    0    1    0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
> 2:  1550729    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0
> 3:  1999180    0    1    0    0    0    1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     1
> 4:  2674608    1    0    0    0    0    1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
> 5:  3048820    0    0    1    0    0    0     1     1     0     0     0     0     1     0
> 6:  3763749    0    0    0    1    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
>    91383 107398 107401 109806 183258 189631 194264 194413 198998 201327 205245 239459
> 1:     0      0      0      0      0      1      0      0      0      1      1      0
> 2:     0      0      0      1      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
> 3:     0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1
> 4:     0      1      1      0      0      0      0      0      1      0      0      0
> 5:     0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0
> 6:     1      0      0      0      0      0      1      1      0      0      1      0
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like the following.

```
dat <- read.table(text = "
track_id   tag1   tag2 
1  1550729  54087 109806 
2  1184201 201327   3668 
", header = TRUE)
dat

molten <- reshape2::melt(dat, id.vars = "track_id")
xtabs(~ track_id + value, molten)
#         value
#track_id  3668 54087 109806 201327
#  1184201    1     0      0      1
#  1550729    0     1      1      0
```